# Can C# connect to a WebSocket using Socket(Not WebSocket) class

Tags: javascript, c#, sockets, websocket

I have a `c#` app that communicates over socket.
I want to code a web app that can connect to `c#` app over socket.
As you know c# has different classes for `Websocket` and `Socket`.

Questions :

1-) If I use `WebSocket` for `JavaScript`, can it connect to existing `Socket` structure on `c#` or is it required to re-code it to `WebSocket` ?

2-) is there any other performance efficent way to do ?

Answer (score 0):

A WebSocket connection uses a socket, but with a predefined way of framing the data, while if you use a socket directly, you can define your own way of framing the data, however the other end must know how the data is framed in order to understand it.

Answering your question: In Javascript you can only connect to sockets that are running as WebSocket, since the WebSocket Javascript client will try to communicate in the "WebSocket" way and won't understand anything different.

However, if you really need Javascript to access a regular socket, you can try to use an intermediary proxy like [WebSockify](https://github.com/kanaka/websockify), but you cannot connect directly.